# Javascript onclick to send Post Request and go to next screen

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an application that, when the user selects an option from a dropdown menu and presses the button "submit," it will send a Post request (which works) but then also transition to the next screen defined by "class.html" (Doesn't work). I know you can do two things on an `onclick` command, but I don't know how to define the path to the next screen so that it doesn't override the post request. For example:

When I do

```
      <button onclick="sendPOST();" 
      class="btn btn-secondary">Submit
      </button>
      <div id="content">
```

The Post request sends fine. However, when I do

```
      <button onclick="sendPOST();" 
      class="btn btn-secondary">
      <a href="./class"> Submit</a> 
      </button>
      <div id="content">
```

It will only go to the next screen, and no Post Request is made. I assume this is because it will execute the `<a href="./class"> Submit</a>`  right away and thus forgo the Post request element of the call. The question I have is how to make the `<a href="./class"> Submit</a>`  a function call. I assume this is how I solve my issue, but I'm stumped and don't know where to begin. Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Do you have access to the server you post to, then just redirect from there

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+post+and+redirect++site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: check this out [submit-button-redirect-to-another-page-in-html](https://programminghead.com/submit-button-redirect-to-another-page-in-html)

Comment: @boki_bo that does not answer this question

Comment: @mplungjan how it does not? there is example using javascript. inside his sendPOST function just set window.location to new url. you can see that as well in that answered post.

Comment: If sendPOST uses AJAX, we can indeed just redirect in the success. as shown in the dupes